# PDF, Document Attached in android

Tags: android

When user press on button open sd card and can select any document in like gallery with Android SDK.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: what exactly you want? please elaborate more as,

There will be no document in gallery ever

Comment: Your question is not clear .

Comment: Assume one screen there is a button Upload Resume. When user press on upload resume button user can select his CV.

Answer (score 1):

Use Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT. On modern systems you can use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT too.

Comment: Thanks greeenapps for your time and for your feedback. It really helpfull.